# Can IEEE floating point errors make me miss a factor in prime number search?

Tags: floating-point, primes

In a simple primality check, it is common practice to check for divisors from 2 up to `max = floor(sqrt(n))`.

In IEEE-defined floating point arithmetic (say for 32 and 64 bit numbers), can it ever happen that floating point errors make you *miss* a factor that is slightly bigger than `max`?

For example, `max = floor(sqrt(REALLY_BIG_N))`, but `(max + 1) * something = REALLY_BIG_N`.

---

If my question is not entirely clear, please comment.

(Note that I'm not interested in primality check alternatives here or avoiding `sqrt` by using `x * x < n` - my question really is about if it will work with IEEE floating point arithmetic.)

Comment: Did you mean `floor` rather than `float`, as in `max = floor(sqrt(REALLY_BIG_N))`?

Comment: Heck yes! I updated - thank you.

Answer (score 3):

No.

I presume that `max+1` is representable as a floating-point value (it is not so large that it is beyond the interval where the floating-point format can represent all integers in the interval).

I also presume the `something` in your `(max+1) * something` is some integer larger than `max`. Otherwise, it (or a smaller factor) would have been found previously in the search for divisors. This implies that *n* ≤ (*max*+1)•(*max*+1).

A properly implemented `sqrt` returns the representable value nearest the square root of its argument. Thus, if the mathematical square root of `n` is at least `x+1`, then `sqrt(n)` must return `x+1` or greater; it cannot return `x` because `x` is farther from the square root than `x+1` is. Therefore, the result of `max = floor(sqrt(n))` not less than the mathematical value of floor(sqrt(*n*)).

For IEEE-754 64-bit binary (hereafter `double`), all integers up to 2<sup>53</sup> are representable. 2<sup>53</sup>+1 is the first integer that is not representable. Therefore, the above tells us that `sqrt(n)` suffices for all `n` up to, but excluding, (2<sup>53</sup>+1)<sup>2</sup>. Of course, many integers that large are not exactly representable in `double` anyway, so you cannot pass them to `sqrt` in the first place.

Comment: I think it's even easier than this:  if `n` is an integer that's exactly representable as a IEEE 754 binary double, then it's easy to see that all divisors of `n` are also exactly representable.  And now it follows that for any divisor `x`, if the exact square root of n is `>= x` then the closest representable double to `sqrt(n)` must also be `>= x`.  No need to limit `n` to less than `(2^53 + 1)^2`.

Comment: ... and of course, if we're allowing `n` such that `n` is *not* exactly representable as a double, and interpreting `floor(sqrt(n)` as `floor(sqrt(nearest_double_to(n)))`, then as you already suggest `n = (2^53 + 1)^2` is going to give a bad `max`.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: Please feel free to contribute your own proof in a new answer. I felt mine was a bit clunky when writing it and would be happy to see another proof that covers more cases.

Answer (score 3):

To complement Eric Postpischil's answer:  Yes, and then again no.  It depends on how we're going to interpret `floor(sqrt(n))` in the case that `n` is really large.

As in Eric's answer, let's assume IEEE 754 binary64 format floating-point and a correctly-rounded `sqrt`, with the usual round-ties-to-even rounding mode in effect.  I'm also assuming access to an arbitrary precision integer type for `n`.

First interpretation: suppose that `n` is allowed to take on any integral value, and that `floor(sqrt(n))` is to be interpreted as `floor(sqrt(convert_to_double(n)))`.  Then there's immediately a problem for `n >= 2^1024 - 2^970`, since `convert_to_double` will overflow at that point.  (I'm assuming that `convert_to_double` is also correctly rounded.)  Starting from the other end, Eric's answer already shows that we're good up to but not including `n = (2^53 + 1)^2`, and as he suggests, `n = (2^53 + 1)^2` is a problem case:  there `convert_to_double(n)` has value `2^106 + 2^54`, one less than the true value, and `sqrt(convert_to_double(n))` will be rounded down to `2^53`, meaning that your trial division function will miss the factor `2^53 + 1`.  However, given that `2^53 + 1` is divisible by `3` and `107`, the trial division will likely have already discovered other factors by that point, so missing `2^53+1` may not be an issue.  In that case, `n = (2^53 + 5)^2` should be considered the first problem case.  (`2^53 + 5` is prime.)

Second interpretation: suppose that `n` is constrained to be a positive integer that's exactly representable as a double.  Then a neat fact is that any divisor of `n` must also be exactly representable as a double:  `n` can be written in the form `m•2^e` for some nonnegative exponent `e` and odd integer `m` with `m < 2^53`, and any divisor of `n` can be written in the form `d•2^f` for some divisor `d` of `m` and exponent `f` with `0 <= f <= e`.  But now if `x` is a divisor of `n` that's smaller than the exact square root of `n`, `x` is exactly representable as a double, so the *nearest* representable double to the square root of `n` must be greater than or equal to `x`.  So a trial division routine that goes up to `floor(sqrt(n))` can't miss `x`.

And just for fun: here we're only worried about values of `n` for which `floor(sqrt(n))` gives a value that's too small.  If you're also interested in cases where `floor(sqrt(n))` gives a value that's too large, the first example occurs *much* earlier, at `n = (2^26 + 1)^2 - 1`.  (Proof left as an exercise.)

Of course, this is all rather academic: if you're doing trial division with numbers larger than `2^106`, you're going to be waiting a *long* time for any result...

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to use floating-point arithmetic when dealing with prime numbers. Ever! Instead of calculating `max`, you should just loop until `d * d > n`, where `d` is the trial divisor and `n` the number being tested. If you must calculate a square root, write your own function that uses only integer arithmetic; Newton's method works perfectly well with integers.

EDIT: Here is a simple function for calculating the integer square root: given an integer `n`, `isqrt(n)` returns the greatest integer `*x` for which `x * x` does not exceed `n`; all the divisions are integer divisions that truncate any fractional remainder:

```
function isqrt(n)
    x := n
    y := (x + n // x) // 2
    while y < x
        x := y
        y := (x + n // x) // 2
    return x
```

Comment: I considered making a similar comment, but there is a reason to use floating-point: Performance. By using `sqrt`, you can establish the limit once, prior to a loop. Calculating `d*d` each iteration requires many more operations. On the other hand, people writing factoring code for the first time usually miss any number of optimizations which might avoid both of these methods.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: There is still no reason to use floating-point arithmetic. You can calculate a square root once, to establish a limit, prior to the loop, using Newton's method but operating on integers.

Comment: In any general-purpose computing platform, the library `sqrt` should be faster than finding a square root with Newton’s method, and it has the advantage of being already available and thoroughly tested.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: In addition to computing the square root, your method also requires time to convert from integer to floating-point and back. And Newton's method converges quickly, so it's not clear to me that the library sqrt with type conversions will beat an integer square root. And in any event, the square root calculation isn't in the inner loop, so it hardly matters. I still say that there is no good reason to use floating-point arithmetic when dealing with prime numbers.

Comment: Intel Core i7-3770 compiling with Apple clang 5.0 for 64-bit: Your code takes 233 CPU cycles to compute the square root of one million; a call to `sqrt`, with conversion to floating-point and back, takes 24 cycles. (Both cases include overhead to call and return from one routine.) For a billion, your code takes 391 cycles, the library takes 24 cycles. And that is just for 32-bit `int`. Using 64-bit `long int`: For a billion, your code takes 784 cycles. The library takes 24. For 2**53, your code takes 1348 cycles. The library takes 24.

Comment: I have to agree with Eric here. Blanket statements like "There is no reason to use floating-point arithmetic when dealing with prime numbers. Ever!" almost never hold universally. Believe it or not, floating-point can be (and often is) (ab)used to speed up integer operations - as Eric has clearly shown. And let's not forget that `sqrt()` is more readable...

Comment: I see the point of the answer, but this is not what I asked for; I am interested in the *correctness* of the `max = floor(sqrt(n))`. An alternative way is nice, but it doesn't tell me if the mentioned method always works correctly, based on FP arithmetics work.